# InDesign create fully rounded corners (border-radius: 50%)

Tags: adobe-indesign, borders, object-styles

[image: goal vs rality]

Hi, I'm trying to achieve something like a CSS "border-radius: 50%" in InDesign. The left shape shows what I`m looking for, the right shape is all I was able to do.

I'm using the "Corner Options" in InDesign CC, set them to 100mm (way more than possible) and the shape to "rounded". But the corners will max out at 25% of the shortest side of my object (right shape). I'm looking for full 50% rounded corners...

How can I achieve a fully rounded corner in InDesign? Best case scenario: I can configure this in an Object Style.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you create a rectangle, you should see these options at the top of your application window

[image]

Select "Rounded" from the drop down and then increase your radius with the box above it

[image]

Comment: These are the "Corner Options" I already used as described above. Sadly these won't go up to a full 50% border radius....

Comment: @FabianSebastian I'm not sure where you're having issues.  I tried resizing my rectangle to any size I wanted and simply increased the radius, via the up/down arrows as I described above.  No issues at any size I tried.

Comment: Just like my example above, the corners in your example aren't fully rounded. If you draw a circle with the exact same height and align them you will see the difference [Corner Demo](http://i.imgur.com/yOTPm7a.png).

Answer (score 2):

This might have to do with your Indesign version. Try instead to make a line and doing a rounded cap (around the vector point). It'll create perfect rounded capsules and is scalable with the shape.

Comment: This is the only solution that makes perfectly round shapes, though a bit hacky.

Answer (score 0):

**Very old** question. I am aware. but....

Use the **corner widget**.

I don't know about setting this as a style, since every shape will presumably be a different size. However, you can completely round corners into a "pill" shape by...

- Clicking the **yellow corner widget** on a rectangle or rectangular frame once to activate it
- It will split into a yelow widget on all 4 corners
- Grab one of these yellow widgets and then drag it inward on the long edge until it stops
- Holding the Shift key down will drag **only** the the corner you click rather than all four.

[image]

The widget will stop dragging when the curve on the short edge hits 50%.

Comment: This doesn't make the border perfectly circular, which is the issue OP is having.

Answer (score -5):

If you need a solution please visit this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bB4Hx_mcJCQ)

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @raja abinesh As a previous poster pointed out, we prefer elaborate answers as videos/links can become obsolete over time. However, I'm alsos afraid the question is looking for an answer in InDesign and the video seems to cover Illustrator.